# Font Awesome Icons in CSS

Tags: css, angular, icons

My code css look like that

```
   .tour-orb {
    z-index: $tour-zindex - 2;
    width: 30px  !important;
    height: 30px  !important;
    position: relative !important;

}

.tour-orb:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome" !important;
    position:absolute !important;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    background-color: #ebe8e8 !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

}
```

I want to change the background image to a Font Awesome icon. I tried to add content to my code code, but it didn't work :

```
 .tour-orb:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome" !important;
    position:absolute !important;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f02d" ;
    background-color: #ebe8e8 !important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

}
```

Is there an other method to add a Font Awesome icon as a background image in css not in HTML?

Comment: Do you have font-awesome added in assets inside `angular.json`

Comment: Yes I added font-awesome inside angular.json